# Will connecting a 1/2" natural gas line to 3/4" line for a fire pit cause issues?

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas, fire-pit

I have a 3/4" natural gas line coming in to the house.  Before the manifold there is a 3/4" line directly to my furnace.

Also there is a manifold that splits into 4 1/2" lines that go to appliances throughout the house.

My Question -  Can i run a 1/2" pipe from the manifold about 15' in the crawl space and connect into a 3/4" flex line that I have buried in the ground to run to a fire pit?  This buried flex line is about 20' long.

I guess it all depends on the BTU's required at the pit burner, but wondering if it would make much of a difference in pressure our output of the final gas going to the pit.

Thanks